# net/http: TLS handshake timeout with KOPS

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, kops

I am getting errors like below,

Validation failed: unexpected error during validation: error listing nodes: Get "https://domainname/api/v1/nodes": net/http: TLS handshake timeout

when I am trying to install the Nginx ingress controller using helm I got this in between.

Comment: the host is probably unreachable from the machine

Answer (score 0):

this was occured due to low resource on master node and I have increase resource of master nodes and it was resolved.

Thx